# The comparative of "environmentally friendly"

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

When using the comparative with *environmentally friendly* would it be correct to say *environmentally friendlier*, or *more environmentally friendly*?

Answer (score 4):

[Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=environmentally%20friendlier,more%20environmentally%20friendly&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows *more environmentally friendly* is by far the most common of the two:

[image: Ngram of environmentally friendlier vs more environmentally friendly]

This is even more stark for the [superlative](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=environmentally%20friendliest,most%20environmentally%20friendly&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3):

[image: Ngram of environmentally friendliest vs most environmentally friendly]

Comment: @z7sgѪ That's usually how language works, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

"more environmentally friendly" is more understandable (understandablier?) to this native  speaker from the Northeastern US. However, I would guess that both are technically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Although they both might be technically correct, I'd say it's harder to parse the latter one, that being:

> more environmentally friendly

Here it might seem like *more* relates to *environmentally*, thus trying to create the phrase *more environmentally*, which in the former example doesn't happen:

> environmentally friendlier

Here it's pretty clear the comparative is *friendlier*, exactly as you want it to. I'd go for this one.

Comment: There's a third possibility: environmentally more friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Either form is perfectly acceptable and neither should be considered incorrect, as *friendly* is part of a set of adjectives that can form a comparative with either the *y* -> *ier* transformation or *more + adj.*

However this is quite an unusual case because *friendly* is an adjective that looks like an adverb.  It used to be an adverb but hasn't been used as such for a very long time.  Most *-ly* adverbs only use the *more + adv.* comparative form. Perhaps this could be one reason that *more environmentally friendly* is preferred.

The form could also depend on context.  For example,

> We need more environmentally friendly buses.

is potentially ambiguous. Is this a call for buses to be friendlier to the environment (probably) or for more buses?

Answer (score 0):

I would use More environmentally friendly, it sounds better said aloud and doesn't involve changing the word friendly.

However I would say that neither 3 terms are the best, and that there are far better sounding alternatives, e.g. greener, or friendlier to the environment

Comment: 'Better sounding' is a subjective judgement.

Comment: I agree with this, because "Environmentally-friendly" is really just phrasal adjective, so modifying it internally is not as natural as applying modifiers to it.

Comment: ‘Environmentally friendly’ is no different from ‘really nice’. It’s an adjective modified by an adverb.

Comment: We'll have to disagree on that. The distinction isn't black & white anyway, but I really do not think of the phrase as "friendly, in an environmental way". The two words together have a distinct meaning imo.

Comment: How things sound can play a good part and should when forming sentences, since if you have 2 equally grammatically correct choices, the better sounding should take preference.

Other examples of where better sounding sentences are not subjective and usually infer grammar errors: There was a apple. ( it sounds wrong and because of that it IS wrong, hence the conception of the whole a vs an rule.

Comment: In this particular case, it's been pointed out that both statements are technically correct, as such it becomes a matter of choice rather than a matter of correctness.